# How to load a sql function on startup with Spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm using `Spring-Boot` for my application, with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.=update`.

How can I ensure that on startup a sql script is executed?
Thereby I want to make sure that at `FUNCTION .. LANGUAGE plpgsql` is present in my `postgresql` db.

Comment: Just add a `schema.sql` or `data.sql` as explained in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-intialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using **XML**.

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-schema.sql"/>
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/foo/sql/db-test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

By using **Annotations** (the following example ought to be placed inside your `@Configuration` class)

```
@Value("classpath:com/foo/sql/db-schema.sql")
private Resource schemaScript;

@Value("classpath:com/foo/sql/db-test-data.sql")
private Resource dataScript;

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final DataSourceInitializer initializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
    initializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator());
    return initializer;
}

private DatabasePopulator databasePopulator() {
    final ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addScript(schemaScript);
    populator.addScript(dataScript);
    return populator;
}
```

Comment: Well you could but Spring Boot by default already checks the existence of a `schema.sql` and `data.sql` if available executes those. So why try and do it yourself when it is as easy as just to include a file.

Comment: True ... most of the time ...

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2753#issuecomment-196717759

Comment: @WoozyCoder Simple and quick solution.