# Execute multiple scripts on application startup

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I defined DataSource as bean:

```
@Bean(name="dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:~/myDB");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    return dataSource;
}
```

It works perfectly, however i need to specify schema for db creation and load data on it. Is there any chances how to excute both scripts (schema and data scripts) just like Spring Data has? The Only thing I found is `datasource.setSchema()` and aswell as i'm concerned i have to specify full path to it. Then how to specify it, if my schema script located in `src/main/resources/` path? (I did exactly, how [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) says, but it fails with a message)

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "~/schema-h2.sql" not found [90079-193]

Thank you for suggestions

Comment: How do you load schema at the moment?

Comment: I can't load it atm, since spring can't find out where it is. As i said earlier `datasource.setSchema(String path);` requires fullpath to sql.

Comment: Did you try with "classpath:schema-h2.sql"

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27859849/280244 , Importent point: `src/main/resources/` becomes the class path, so a file `src/main/resources/test.sql` have to been loaded with `classpath:test.xml`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;

@Bean(name="dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
   DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
   dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
   dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:~/myDB");
   dataSource.setUsername("sa");
   dataSource.setPassword("");

   // schema init
   Resource initSchema = new ClassPathResource("script/schema.sql");
   DatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(initSchema);
   DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, dataSource);

   return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: I made some workaround and it exactly what i need! I managed to run schema and data scripts.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1**

Update your connection url with these additional options:

```
DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS
```

**Solution 2**

You should have a application.properties file in your src/main/resources which should contain these propertes:

```
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.initialize=true
```

**Workaround**

You could aim for putting INIT params with script location script in your connection url (being one of the options):

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/schema.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/data.sql'
```

> This functionality is enabled via the INIT property. Note that
> multiple commands may be passed to INIT, but the semicolon delimiter
> must be escaped, as in the example below.

Comment: So, there is no chance to do it via spring?

Comment: From: `jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/schema.sql'\;RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/data.sql'"
`  you might want to remove the final `"`. Also, it gives me this error when I try to run two scripts instead of one: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: URL format error; must be "jdbc:h2:...`

Comment: @PJ_Finnegan There's a typo here and in the h2 docs. The backslash for the semi-colon itself needs to be escaped, ie. `INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/schema.sql'\\;RUNSCRIPT FROM '~/data.sql'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Spring official document - Creating an Embedded Database Programmatically](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-embedded-database-java).

```java
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public static DataSource H2DataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setName("testdb")
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScripts("Your scripts in /resources")
                .build();
    }
```